# Why does my code insert 3 spaces after encrypting the second word?

Tags: c, cs50

please have a look at the following code and the screenshot. For some reason it prints 3 spaces, thereby moving the key 2 too much.

[image: picture]

The code should actually behave like this:

```
Plaintext:      M|e|e|t| |m|e| |a|t| |t|h|e| |P|a|r|k
Keyword:        a|b|c|d|e|a|b|c|d|e|a|b|c|d|e|a|b|c|d
Move letter by: 0|1|2|3|4|0|1|2|3|4|0|1|2|3|4|0|1|2|3|
```

But for some reason, it does not do one space after "me" like it did after "Meet" but 3 spaces...

Yes, I tried debugging it myself.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[1])
{
    bool keySuccesful = false;
    string keyword;
    do
    {
        // Check whether argc is 2. If not print the following. Else turn argv[1] into an int and set keySuccesful to true.
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            printf("You didn't submit a valid encryption key.\n");
            printf("Please check your input and re-run the programm.\n");
            printf("We require an integer as encryption key.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Key needs to be converted from string to int
            keyword = argv[1];
            keySuccesful = true;
        }
    } while (!keySuccesful);  // repeat while keySuccessful is false.

    string plain = get_string("plaintext: "); // Get plaintext/

    printf("ciphertext: "); // Print "ciphertext: "

    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(plain); k++)  // loop through each character of the plaintext, start at index 0, until the length of the string.
    {
        for (int u = 0; u <strlen(keyword); u++)
        {
            int g = keyword[u] - 97;
            if(isalpha(plain[k])) // check that chacater is a letter
            {
                if (isupper(plain[k])) // if letter is uppercase
                {
                    printf("%c", ((((plain[k] - 65)+g)%26)+65));
                }
                if (islower(plain[k])) // if letter is lowercase
                {
                    printf("%c", ((((plain[k] - 97)+g)%26)+97));
                }
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", plain[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the program output _as text_. No pictures of text unless the formatting/font is relevant.

Comment: Do you actually want to preserve spaces, or skip them? How do you move a space 5 places, e.g.?

Comment: Please give an exact description of the problem you're solving. The interface is program nr, where nr is a key? For a Viginere I'd expect 2 arguments (a text file for plain and a keyword as key, no number.

Comment: It seems at a space you skip a key letter and keep a plain space? Weird system.

Comment: [why output text should be posted as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). and [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you **only** increment `k` inside the `isalpha` block. Consequently, a space will/may be handled multiple time, i.e. until `for (int u = 0; u <strlen(keyword); u++)` ends.

Try:

```
        // k++; Remove this line
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c", plain[k]);
    }
    k++;  // Insert this line
```

Besides that your nested loops are wrong as you may increment `k` too much in the inner loop and therefore read out of bounds.

Consider changing

```
for (int u = 0; u <strlen(keyword); u++)
```

to

```
for (int u = 0; u <strlen(keyword) && k < strlen(plain); u++)
```

Note: The reason your code seemed to work for the first space is that the "Meet " just happens to have the same length as your keyword. Consequently, the inner loop just happened to stop after processing the space once. But for "me " that is not the case so extra spaces will be printed

Comment: Hi, I implemented your changes. It helped, getting rid of the extra spaces. Thanks for that. For some reason, I'm still not getting the correct output. Do you have any idea why? Thanks a lot. See this: https://github.com/jstrnbrg/question/commit/2d7a3d6e353f735e4bf63fdf2edcf085a13afd63